# number format in php 999.99

Tags: php, numbers, format

Please help me with the number format in php 
for example
I have some calculations, like a+b=c I want answer as 999.99 format in php I've read the number_format,sprintf but its not useful. please give me some useful ideas. My final result should be in 999.99 format.

Comment: a,b,c are sample digits like 1+2=3 i want result 3 to be shown in 999.99 format or you can say in 003.00 format. another example 10+1=11 then it should be 011.00 format.

Answer (score 11):

Per the 'not useful' documentation:

```
$num = 999.98353;
$num = number_format($num, 2, '.', '');
```

If you take the time to actually [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), there are pertinent examples.

Comment: If a+b=c, even though c is a single/double digit with out decimal point (for example 1,2,5 etc) i should show c as 00c.00 if its single digit, or 0cc.00 if its double digit and if its three digit number no need to add one zero before the number. I hope my question reached you. I want to show my total in CANADA money format. Please help me in this regard of money format –

Comment: number_format does that form you. Alternatively see http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php. Read the docs . . .

Answer (score 3):

In addition to number_format, you can use sprintf

```
$a = 999;
$b = .99;
$c = $a + $b;
echo sprintf('%03.2f', $c); // 999.99
```

Comment: a,b,c are sample digits like 1+2=3 i want result 3 to be shown in 999.99 format or you can say in 003.00 format. another example 10+1=11 then it should be 011.00 format.

Comment: Use str_pad to left pad with zero to the desired length:`$a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $c = $a + $b;
    echo str_pad(sprintf('%.2f', $c), 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); // 003.00`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.it really helped me a lot. I did it in another method and it worked, $a=1;$b=2;$c=$a+$b;                                 
$final_result = (strlen(number_format((float)$c, 2, '.', '')) < 6) ? '0'.number_format((float)$result, 2, '.', '') : number_format((float)$result, 2, '.', '');
echo '<b>'.$final_result.'</b>'; digits may be single or double it'll give the desired result i.e 999.99 format. Thanks for your time. it was a great help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = 999.98353;
$num1 = 10;
$num2 = $num + $num1;
echo number_format($num2, 2, '.', '');   // output 1009.98
```

Comment: If a+b=c, even though c is a single/double digit with out decimal point (for example 1,2,5 etc) i should show c as 00c.00 if its single digit, or 0cc.00 if its double digit and if its three digit number no need to add one zero before the number. I hope my question reached you. I want to show my total in CANADA money format. Please help me in this regard of money format

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$a = 500.3755;
$b = 600.9855;
$c = $a + $b;
echo number_format($c, 2, '.', ''); //1101.36
echo number_format($c, 2, '.', ','); //1,101.36
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$c = sprintf('%0.2f',$a)+sprintf('%0.2f',$b);
```

Or you can also try :

```
$c = $a+ $b; // If $c = 999.9999
$c = substr($c, 0, 2); // $c is now the string 999.9999
echo( number_format($c-1,2) );  // Will output 998.99
```

Comment: If a+b=c, even though c is a single/double digit with out decimal point (for example 1,2,5 etc) i should show c as 00c.00 if its single digit, or 0cc.00 if its double digit and if its three digit number no need to add one zero before the number. I hope my question reached you. I want to show my total in CANADA money format. Please help me in this regard of money format

Comment: I did it in another method and it worked, `$a=1;$b=2;$c=$a+$b; $final_result = (strlen(number_format((float)$c, 2, '.', '')) < 6) ? '0'.number_format((float)$result, 2, '.', '') : number_format((float)$result, 2, '.', ''); echo '<b>'.$final_result.'</b>';` digits may be single or double it'll give the desired result i.e 999.99 format. Thanks for your time. it was a great help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $a = 1234.5678;
    $b = 1234.5678;
    $num = round(($a + $b), 2);
    echo number_format($num, 2, '.', ',');
```

number_format works, try posting some of your codes.

Comment: If a+b=c, even though c is a single/double digit with out decimal point (for example 1,2,5 etc) i should show c as 00c.00 if its single digit, or 0cc.00 if its double digit and if its three digit number no need to add one zero before the number. I hope my question reached you. I want to show my total in CANADA money format. Please help me in this regard of money format