# How can round to 2 decimals in laravel?

Tags: laravel, rounding

I have this. Its made in laravel

```
public function render()
{

    $percentageNotAnswered = ($noanswer * 100) / $mytickets;
```

And also this:

```
            <span class="text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-700"> {{ $noanswer ?? "" }} </span>
            <span class="text-sm  text-gray-500">  {{ $percentageNotAnswered ?? '' }}% </span>

            <div class="text-gray-500">Tickets with no Answer</div>
         </div>
```

And it show the result like 33.333333333333%
How can I round to just 2 decimals?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show a number to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-two-decimal-places)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [number format in php 999.99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701077/number-format-in-php-999-99)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple php function:

```
round(($noanswer * 100) / $mytickets, 2);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Thanks, I saw the documentation but I didn't know how to implement. Not a programmer, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Its PHP [round()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function.

So you wanna use:

```
$percentageNotAnswered = round(($noanswer * 100) / $mytickets), 2);
```

It is basically `round($number,$decimal_places)`